# Slice a tensor in Caffe2

Tags: deep-learning, keras, caffe2

I write a model converter for keras to Caffe2. Unfortunately the strided convolution with `padding='same'` is implemented differently in Caffe2. Namely there is a shift of 1 pixel in x and y.

How can I slice a tensor in Caffe2, to correct the offset?